# How to execute a MDX query of SQL Analysis Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas, analysis, adomd.net

I want to execute a SQL Analysis Query in C#. I have successfully connected to Analysis database using the below code:

```
Server DM_Server = new Server();
Database AS_Database = new Database();
DM_Server.Connect(//SQL Analysis Server Connection String);
AS_Database = DM_Server.Databases[//Database name];
```

I have a SQL query like

```
SELECT FLATTENED PredictAssociation()
From
[Mining Structure Name]
NATURAL PREDICTION JOIN
(SELECT (SELECT 1 AS [UserId]) AS [Vm]) AS t
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use [ADOMD.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/adomd/multidimensional-models-adomd-net-client/adomd-net-client-programming?) which is the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient namespace. It is also available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.retail.amd64/).

```
AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection(
    "Data Source=localhost;Catalog=YourDatabase");
conn.Open();

string commandText = @"SELECT FLATTENED 
    PredictAssociation()
    From
    [Mining Structure Name]
    NATURAL PREDICTION JOIN
    (SELECT (SELECT 1 AS [UserId]) AS [Vm]) AS t ";
AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand(commandText, conn);
AdomdDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
   Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(dr[0]));
}

dr.Close();
conn.Close();
```

In the code sample I borrowed the DMX query from the question. But any MDX or DAX query should also work.

Update: ADOMD.NET (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient) for .NET Core is [available](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64/) in on nuget now. This is an official Microsoft maintained library.

Comment: GregGalloway: I had already figured out this answer. But anyways thanks

Comment: @BhavnaBeri sure. You might post your own answer next time to help the community. Happy you figured it out

Comment: Heads up: Right now ADOMD.NET does not work on .NET Core.

Comment: @IsaacLyman I have added a link to the officially maintained version for .NET Core.